# How do I combine 2 onclick functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, xapi

Hi there I am trying to combine 2 javascript onClick function so that they only fire once both have been clicked, this is what I have currently attempted.

Javascript

```
click.onclick = function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
       console.log("Clicks counted " + I);
   }
}

click2.onclick = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      console.log("Clicks counted " + I);
  }
}

if (click.onclick && click2.onclick === true) {
   console.log("You have clicked on both onClicks");
}
```

HTML

```
<section>
    <button id="button-click">Nice</button>
    <button id="button-click-2">Even nicer</button>
</section>
```

Super simple I know, but I just wanted to figure out how to do this as it's for an API call so requires both buttons to be clicked and then send a statement.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `xapi`?

Comment: What's the point of these for loops...? Also, you need an external variable to store state. Like `let button1clicks = 0;` at the top of your script. Now increment this variable inside the click handler. This way you can check how many times either button was clicked at any point. The if block at the bottom is bad because a) each test has to be stated separately, in full b) checking for `=== true` will fail because `.onclick` is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function which checks a value. This value is made up by using bitwise or with `1` or `2`, for more buttons double the value for each one.

In the checking function, check the value which is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, for two check against `3`.

```js
let clickButtons = 0;

function check() {
    if (clickButtons === 3) console.log("You have clicked on both onClicks");
}

document.getElementById("button-click").addEventListener('click', function() {
   clickButtons |= 1;
   check();
});

document.getElementById("button-click-2").addEventListener('click', function() {
   clickButtons |= 2;
   check();
});
```

```html
<section>
    <button id="button-click">Nice</button>
    <button id="button-click-2">Even nicer</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I think this is exactly what I am looking for, just so I understand it a bit better would you be able to tell me the values for a 3 button version? would be much appreciated, thanks for answering the question as well.

Comment: the take, as i wrote, for the first button the value `1`, the next `2` and the last one `4`  (always 2 times more the the previous button) and as sum test against `7` which is `2 ** 3 - 1`.

Comment: That's great thank you so much, this really helped.